# Entity Framework 6 Primary Key configuration issue on save of Entities

Tags: entity-framework, wcf-ria-services

I'm trying to save few entities with this code:

```
this.UserService.Users.Add(eUser);

if (SelectedRewindItems != null && SelectedRewindItems.Count > 0)
{
    foreach (var ug in SelectedRewindItems)
    {
                HpmModel.Usergroup nUg = new HpmModel.Usergroup();
                decimal numId;
                var a = Decimal.TryParse(ug.Key.ToString(), out numId);
                nUg.Groupid = numId;
                nUg.Userid = eUser.Userid;
               // eUser.Usergroups.Add(nUg);
                this.UserService.Usergroups.Add(nUg);

    }
}

var submitOp = this.UserService.SubmitChanges();
IsSuccess = true;

ActionMessageOnButtonSuccess = User.Fname + " " + User.Lname + " Added Successfully !!";

string message = null;

if (submitOp.EntitiesInError.Any())
{
    message = string.Empty;
    Entity entityInError = submitOp.EntitiesInError.First();

    if (entityInError.EntityConflict != null)
    {
                EntityConflict conflict = entityInError.EntityConflict;

                foreach (var cm in conflict.PropertyNames)
                {
                    message += string.Format("{0}", cm);
                }
    }
    else if (entityInError.ValidationErrors.Any())
    {
                message += "\r\n" + entityInError.ValidationErrors.First().ErrorMessage;
    }

    MessageBox.Show(message);
}
else 
{
    MessageBox.Show("Submit Done");
}
```

But I'm getting this error:

> System.InvalidOperationException was unhandled by user code
>   HResult=-2146233079
>   Message=The changes to the database were committed successfully, but an error occurred while updating the object context. The ObjectContext might be in an inconsistent state.
>
> Inner exception message: Saving or accepting changes failed because more than one entity of type 'HpmModel.Usergroup' have the same primary key value. Ensure that explicitly set primary key values are unique. Ensure that database-generated primary keys are configured correctly in the database and in the Entity Framework model. Use the Entity Designer for Database First/Model First configuration. Use the 'HasDatabaseGeneratedOption" fluent API or 'DatabaseGeneratedAttribute' for Code First configuration.
>
> Source=EntityFramework
>
> StackTrace: 
>          at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectContext.SaveChangesToStore(SaveOptions options, IDbExecutionStrategy executionStrategy, Boolean startLocalTransaction)
>          at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectContext.<>c__DisplayClass2a.b__27()
>          at System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DefaultExecutionStrategy.Execute[TResult](Func`1 operation)
>          at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectContext.SaveChangesInternal(SaveOptions options, Boolean executeInExistingTransaction)
>          at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectContext.SaveChanges(SaveOptions options)
>          at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectContext.SaveChanges()
>          at OpenRiaServices.DomainServices.EntityFramework.LinqToEntitiesDomainService`1.InvokeSaveChanges(Boolean retryOnConflict) in c:\Code\Repos\openriaservices\OpenRiaServices.DomainServices.EntityFramework\Framework\LinqToEntitiesDomainService.cs:line 145
>          at OpenRiaServices.DomainServices.EntityFramework.LinqToEntitiesDomainService`1.PersistChangeSet() in c:\Code\Repos\openriaservices\OpenRiaServices.DomainServices.EntityFramework\Framework\LinqToEntitiesDomainService.cs:line 138
>          at OpenRiaServices.DomainServices.Server.DomainService.PersistChangeSetInternal()
>          at OpenRiaServices.DomainServices.Server.DomainService.Submit(ChangeSet changeSet)
>          InnerException: System.InvalidOperationException
>          HResult=-2146233079
>          Message=Saving or accepting changes failed because more than one entity of type 'HpmModel.Usergroup' have the same primary key value. Ensure that explicitly set primary key values are unique. Ensure that database-generated primary keys are configured correctly in the database and in the Entity Framework model. Use the Entity Designer for Database First/Model First configuration. Use the 'HasDatabaseGeneratedOption" fluent API or 'DatabaseGeneratedAttribute' for Code First configuration.
>          Source=EntityFramework
>          StackTrace:
>               at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectStateManager.FixupKey(EntityEntry entry)
>               at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.EntityEntry.AcceptChanges()
>               at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectContext.AcceptAllChanges()
>               at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectContext.SaveChangesToStore(SaveOptions options, IDbExecutionStrategy executionStrategy, Boolean startLocalTransaction)
>          InnerException:

When I checked the Database Entities got saved but still  it is giving me this issues.

Is this because I'm trying save them after saving User & Then UserGroup entities separatly. or Child Entities should get saved with Parent Entities. I'm a beginner so facing challanges.

Comment: Any One Help please look into my issue

Answer (score 3):

After wasting a lot of time, I came to know that I need to fix my EDMX file & Entity Code.
So I added in my entity:

```
[DatabaseGenerated( DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
```

In the SSDL file in my Users  -> Usersgroup (1-M) Relationship 
Usersgroup Id Node I Added:

```
StoreGeneratedPattern="Identity" [SSDL]
```

In CSDL:

```
ed:StoreGeneratedPattern="Identity"
```

In my code:

```
this.UserService.Users.Add(eUser);

if (SelectedRewindItems != null && SelectedRewindItems.Count > 0)
{
    foreach (var ug in SelectedRewindItems)
    {
        HpmModel.Usergroup nUg = new HpmModel.Usergroup();
        decimal numId;
        var a = Decimal.TryParse(ug.Key.ToString(), out numId);
        nUg.Groupid = numId;
        nUg.Userid = eUser.Userid;
        eUser.Usergroups.Add(nUg);
    }
}
```

After applying these changes, `SaveChanges()` worked.

This [blog post](https://web.archive.org/web/20171109024547/http://www.ladislavmrnka.com/2011/03/the-bug-in-storegeneratedpattern-fixed-in-vs-2010-sp1/) helped me.

Comment: I had the same issue using an Oracle DB. PK were auto incremented over an insert trigger, but EF6 complained that duplicate PK entries were set. I had to change all PK Properties in the model to "StoreGeneratedPattern" => Identity (replacing "none").

Comment: save my ass bro. I search last 2 hour.  @akirti